# What is the significance of a library being written in pure C#

Tags: c#

I have come across many c# libraries and many say their libraries are written in pure c#. Why is this an advantage over other libraries.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I suppose one benefit is that you don't have to deal with interoperability issues, or have several different build tools and maintenance scripts. It depends, of course, on what you're doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The advantage is the libraries are not tied to any architecture (x86/x86_64/...). This is a plus because:

1. The library can be easily recompiled under x64/x86/Any CPU if you
   have the source (and sometimes if you do not). Recompiling native
   code is much more difficult.
2. The library can be run on non-x86
   devices like ARM Microsoft Surface tablets. This means, you can have
   your application portable between desktop/tablets easily.
3. As was
   already pointed out, you can run your code under Mono on Linux or
   under some other version of the .NET Framework like .NET Micro
   Framework (with limitations, of course).

Answer (score 8):

With no external dependencies it could "in theory" be run in another environment where C# is supported - e.g. [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Comment: In practice also! I have several small own libraries that run very well under e.g. MonoTouch.